# HTML - Vertically align responsive content

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align content inside of a block - the content is an image on left (no text under it) and a paragraph of text. 
When the text is on a large screen, the height of the paragraph is smaller than the height of the image and thus the paragraph should be vertically aligned to middle. On the other hand, while the content is displayed on smaller screen, the paragraph's height is bigger than the image and the image should be vertically aligned.
Centering the image is easy, because I know the height, but how to handle responsive paragraph? Everything i have tried resulted in some weird behavior - for example blocks overlapping each other when on a small screen. So I start to thing that its not possible by CSS and I need some Javascript for it.

HTML:

```
<div class="entry">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu rhoncus eros. Nunc ac mollis velit. Cras vitae odio fringilla, consectetur felis id, maximus quam. Nulla placerat felis nec malesuada mattis. </p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu rhoncus eros. Nunc ac mollis velit. Cras vitae odio fringilla, consectetur felis id, maximus quam. Nulla placerat felis nec malesuada mattis.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.entry {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 120px;
    position: relative;
}

div.entry img {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

The example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/46psK/2583/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved using Flexible box method. Set the parent container as `flex` and align the items inside to be centered along the `cross-axis`

```css
div.entry {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 120px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
div.entry img {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu rhoncus eros. Nunc ac mollis velit. Cras vitae odio fringilla, consectetur felis id, maximus quam. Nulla placerat felis nec malesuada mattis.</p>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu rhoncus eros. Nunc ac mollis velit. Cras vitae odio fringilla, consectetur felis id, maximus quam. Nulla placerat felis nec malesuada mattis.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thaks a lot! This is exactly what I wanted. But I see its not supported in IE less than 10. Is there any way how to make it work even for at least IE 8?

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Unfortunately it can't be supported. But please don't develop for IE8 and IE9. They are hated by Microsoft themselves :P

Comment: I know, but tell this to the people who are using Windows XP ... and they unfortunately still exist!

Answer (score 0):

Try using display: table-cell. The modified css is as below.

```
    div.entry {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     min-height: 100px;
     padding: 0 10px;
     display: table;
    }
    div.entry img, div.entry p {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    div.entry img {
     margin:0 10px 0 0;
     width: 100px;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this doesn't vertically align the image when the height of text is bigger than the image